# How can I cancel a soon to be failing transaction in Ethers.js?

Tags: ethers.js

Let's take the following example:

```ts
let contract = new Contract(address, abi, signer);
let tx: ContractTransaction = await contract.foo();
```

Say I initiate `tx`, a transaction calling the `foo()` method and could possibly fail. I would like for the transaction to pass as quickly as possibly. But in case it fails (i.e., gets front ran), I would rather be able to cancel it than see it fail in order to minimize spent gas. How would that be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To cancel a transaction, you need to know it's nonce.

Then you can send a tiniest transaction with a higher gas price so that it gets preference.

```
const tx = {
  nonce: nonceOfPendingTx,
  to: ethers.constants.AddressZero,
  data: '0x',
  gasPrice: gasPriceHigherThanPendingTx
}; // costs 21000 gas

signer.sendTransaction(tx);
```